# Doubt on Open set in R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ Is $A+B=\{a+b \mid a \in A , b \in B\}$ may open even when both $A$ and $B$ are not open in $\mathbb{R}$, under the standard topology on reals. If yes then please give examples?

Also, Can we consider this as an example $A=\mathbb{Q}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}$$-\mathbb{Q}.$
Here I am a bit confused about the union of two sets and the sum of two sets as we know the union of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$$-\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, Is the sum of these two sets is also
$\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $\{0\}+\{0\}$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\{0\}.$

Comment: @Saini Dosen't that tell you enough?. $\{0\}+\{1\}=\{1\}$ and singletons are closed in $\Bbb{R}$ with usual topology

Comment: @Saini There's a result by Steinhaus that might interest you, if $A$ is a set of positive Lebesgue measure then $A-A$ contains an interval around $0$

Comment: The sum of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, not $\mathbb R$. Indeed, a rational number + an irrational number is irrational.

Comment: Sorry I edit my question, Actually my doubt is $A+B $ can be open even when both $A$ and $B$ are not open?

Comment: For an example, consider $A=[0,1)$ and $B=(0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your own example. Take $A=(\Bbb{R\setminus Q})\cup\{0\}$ which is neither open nor closed and take $B=\Bbb{Q}$.

Then each rational $q\in \Bbb{Q}$ as it is  ($0+q$) lies in $A+B$ and so does every irrational $r$ as it is $r+0$ . So the sum is the whole of $\Bbb{R}$ as a set. So you have sum of neither open nor closed sets give you a set which is simultaneously open and closed under the usual topology.